# attributes declared in a static methods, are they static? how to acess them?

Tags: java, methods, static

are these local variables considered to be static attributes?
how would you access them?

```
public static int getTotal() {

   int basket;
   int tax = 5;

   return basket + tax
}
```

Comment: these are not attributes, these are function variables. You can't access them from outside this function.

Answer (score 2):

Both variables basket and tax are local, it doesn't matter whether it is a static method or not.

You cannot access local variables outside of the method they are declared in.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

Answer (score 0):

Both are local, can be used only inside the method.

Answer (score 0):

A field member is `static` only if it's been defined in the body of the class and by using the `static` keyword explicitly , indeed `static` variables are not allowed to be defined in the methods!

Please refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) page for more information on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if you've declared it in a method, it's not an attribute. It only has local scope, like any other method-level variable. If you wanted static attributes, you could declare them in the class itself:

```
static int tax;
```

and even initialize them inside a static init block:

```
static{
        tax = 5; 
      }
```

which can then be used by the `getTotal` method, as well as by other methods in the class.

I'm assuming that you asked this question because you're getting some errors. Your problem isn't that it's a static method, take a look:

```
public static int getTotal() {

       int basket =0;
       int tax = 5;

       return basket + tax;
    }
```

You forgot to initialize `basket` (it won't compile otherwise), and you also forgot a semi-colon on the last line.